# Is Bruce Banner considered an 'Avenger'?

Tags: marvel, avengers, the-incredible-hulk

I'm not a big follower of Marvel, but from what I know, 'The Hulk' is one of the founding members of the Avengers team, but the thing is, can Banner be considered also a member? They mainly want and use Hulk for the brute force but during the times he is Bruce Banner is he also considered a member of the Avengers or even was asked and agree to the idea? Or is he Hulk 24/7?

Was it explained or commented in any comic, TV show or movie?

Comment: The Quinjet in Thor: Ragnarok greets him as "The Strongest Avenger" when he is in 'Bruce' mode and identifies himself as "Banner" ;)

Comment: Also worth noting that while Banner is very weak, he is incredibly brilliant. On par with the Tony Stark, Hank Pym, and Reed Richards of the comics. Definitely worth the Avenger part.

Comment: Hypothetical question: would you consider Tony Stark an Avenger? Or is he only an Avenger when he's in his Iron Man suit?

Comment: No one wants to tell him otherwise in case it makes him angry...

Comment: @F1Krazy funny you mention that, because at the end of "Iron Man 2", when Nick Fury gives Tony his assessment results for recruitment into the Avengers, "Iron Man" IS recommended but Tony IS NOT: https://youtube.com/watch?v=sbM9Gaan-XY Obviously, that decision gets changed later and Tony joins as a full member

Comment: Yes, he's the strongest Avenger

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes

The [official Marvel page for Bruce](https://www.marvel.com/characters/hulk-bruce-banner/in-comics) mentions his affiliation as:

> GROUP AFFILIATION
> **Avengers, Defenders**

It’s also worth noting that Bruce and the Hulk are one and the same, you can’t have one without the other and so Bruce must be an Avenger by default just because of that.

We then have the fact that Bruce in the MCU shows up at multiple “Avengers meetings” and if it was only the Hulk who was a member this wouldn’t be the case. Bruce is a brilliant scientist, similar to Tony Stark but works in a different field and so even on his own he is a massive asset.

Also as @NKCampbell notes in a comment in *Thor: Ragnarok* the Quinjet notes Bruce as the *”Strongest Avenger”* when he is Bruce and gives the password *”Banner”*.

> **QUINJET (V.O.):** Voice Activation required.
>
> **BANNER:** Banner.
>
> **QUINJET (V.O.):** Welccome, Strongest Avenger.
>
> <sub>*Thor: Ragnarok*</sub>

In *The Avengers* when Natasha brings Bruce in she tells him Fury is only after Bruce not the Hulk which suggests they are recruiting Bruce **and** the Hulk to the Avengers.

> **NATASHA:** Nick Fury seems to trust you. But now I need you to come in.
>
> [...]
>
> **BANNER:** What does Fury want me to do? Swallow it?
>
> **NATASHA:** Well, he wants you to find it. It's been taken. It emits a gamma signature that's too weak for us to trace. There's no one that knows gamma radiation like you do. If there was, that's where I'd be.
>
> **BANNER:** So Fury isn't after the monster?
>
> **NATASHA:** Not that he's told me.
>
> <sub>*The Avengers*</sub>